# Why are functions on the object being executed from a self executing function?

Tags: javascript

I have an application that in debug mode is written in many separate javascript files, but are loaded synchronously as part of the head block of a page.  In release, I merge all these files together and minifiy them. Today I kept finding an error in the minified version, so I loaded up a single merged file to debug the issue and found that one library was self executing a function and it was causing other functions defined on `window` to be executed.

I've repo'd the behavior here with a generic object, doesn't matter if its window or not:

```
<head>
    <script>
        var a = {}

        a.X = function x(){
            console.log("shouldn't be executed");
        }

        (function(a){
            console.log("self execution");
        }(a));
     </script>
</head>
```

In this example, I get the output of

```
self execution 
shouldn't be executed
```

If I change the call to be

```
<head>
    <script>
        var a = {}

        function x(){
            console.log("shouldn't be executed");
        }

        a.X = x;

        (function(a){
            console.log("self execution");
        }(a));
     </script>
</head>
```

Then I just get

```
self execution
```

Which is what I expected.  In the first example, why is `X` getting called when `a` is passed to the self executing function?

Comment: I am puzzled why such a question would get that many upvotes in a short time... is it because it is tagged Javascript and has behavior that is not immediately obvious...?

Comment: Living proof that you should insert semicolons =D

Comment: yeah, sometimes those semis do matter, and we can see how confsuing it can be when they do and are missing! lesson learned: always use semis.

Comment: @Lekensteyn it's an interesting puzzle, and it's not about setting up event handlers in a `for` loop.

Comment: @Esailija also, lines starting with unary plus and minus

Comment: You know, making example/explanation code with a's and x's isn't going to help us understand your issue at all. Honestly, the code may be simple, but with such meaningless names, I struggle to understand what you're aiming to do. It's just as bad as stuff like "foo". So I don't get the goal, but speaking in general: you probably checked, but in case... when things work in separate files but not when minified, then I'd check code order and the minifier itself. Copy-pasting in the wrong order for example. Also, some minifiers will break code by forgetting that this or that space/etc. was needed.

Comment: this bug is a feature

Comment: @Esailija: OP does insert semicolons, but missed some. I'd argue that it's living proof that you should use a more sensible operator for an IIFE, in place of one that can be misinterpreted.

Comment: @CrazyTrain they can be caught by jshint though

Comment: Sure, but it's nicer when there's nothing to catch.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are missing the `;` after you assign the function to `a.X`.

Semi-colon insertion is *not* triggered.

The `(` and `)` around the anonymous function are used to call the previous function, and its return value is assigned to `X`.

i.e. what you have is equivalent to:

```
var a = {};

a.X = (function x(){
    console.log("shouldn't be executed");
}(
    (function(a){
        console.log("self execution");
    }(a))
));
```

Incidentally, this issue is a good advert for [JS Lint](http://jslint.com/), which would have picked it up.

Comment: LOL I just noticed that. This is why you **should use** semicolons!

Comment: @asawyer — Thinking too far ahead of what I was typing, fixed.

Comment: Ha, awesome. Thanks. Also this makes perfect sense why it works when I load up multiple files, they don't get the opportunity to execute each other in this way. When I merged everything into one file suddenly the semicolons mattered.

Comment: @Neal: Or you should simply use a safer operator in this situation. The flaw in the code is a matter of perspective.

Comment: @CrazyTrain parentheses are classic. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Just about any prefix unary operator that isn't overloaded as a binary operator. A common substitute is the `!` operator.

Comment: @CrazyTrain I can try that, but I doubt it will become popular too quickly

Comment: @JanDvorak: Facebook has been known to use it, as do those (such as myself) who elide semicolons in their code, which I do both in JS and Go. It's just a matter of altering coding habits. Nice thing is that once you're in the pattern, you won't be caught off guard, whereas if you do typically use semicolons, but you forget some (like OP did), then you get hit with the bug unless you're using a safer operator.

Comment: @CrazyTrain arguing how development is like without using obvious tools like jshint is just wrong. Is there a tool that will tell when leaving out semicolon causes the statement on next line be treated as part of current statement?

Comment: @Esailija: It's not wrong to argue that there are better, safer, more sensible operators to use in certain situations. And I never said that a linter shouldn't be used. Where'd you get that idea?

Comment: @CrazyTrain by saying that one can forget semicolons you imply the absence of any tools. Because it cannot happen when using a tool. Whereas when coding without semicolons one needs human judgement to determine if the code is buggy as you say you "won't be caught off guard" because you have developed a habit. When you compare these, both are just as worse off when not using any tools, but semicolons are far better off when using tools. Although this is only because I imagine there is not a tool that could detect when a statement on a new line wasn't intended to follow the previous one.

Comment: @Esailija: I see what you're saying. I just meant for those who aren't using such a tool. Not saying that one shouldn't. Regarding a tool to detect when a statement on a new line wasn't intended to extend the previous, such checks could be added to something like jshint that would follow common coding practices. For example, adding a *leading* semicolon when a line starts with `[` or `(` would be testable. Though I find that a missing `;` before a starting `[` is much more visible than a missing `;` here and there among a page full of them.

Comment: @devshorts Semicolons always mattered... Not just suddenly. Always.

Comment: @davel "mattered" should have really been "manifested". I realize they always matter, but in this case the problem only showed when files were merged :)

Answer (score 3):

It have something to do with semicolon injection because when I put semicolon it work as expected:

```
    var a = {}

    a.X = function x(){
        console.log("shouldn't be executed");
    }; // added semicolon

    (function(a){
        console.log("self execution");
    }(a));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed a semicolon `;` after your `a.X = function x() { ...} ;`

**i.e.**

```
a.X = function x(){
   console.log("shouldn't be executed");
};
```